# Help to draw a pattern in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pattern

I would like to draw the following picture:
[image]

When I use the pattern feature it does not let me color in the shapes, could someone help?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: How did you use the pattern feature? How should we be able to tell you what you did wrong if you don't show us what you did? I think it would be best to not use the pattern feature and just draw the hexagons and triangles yourself in a loop. That is much more precise.

Comment: draw it for me pls

Comment: for those pictures I use asymptote. If you use texlive, you also have it in your PC.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a very inflexible approach (but at least the side length of the hexagons is given by the PGFMath function `a`).

The `\ifnum` and `\ifodd` mess makes sure that no triangles are drawn on the wrong place and not multiple times.

The `\columnCheck` is for alternating the colors in the every third and fourth row again.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  polygon path/.style n args={3}{% 1: phase, 2: radius, 3: n
    insert path={plot[sharp cycle, samples at={0, ..., \pgfinteval{#3-1}}]
      ({#1+\x*360/(#3)}:{#2})}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={a=.75;}, thick,
  @/.style args={#1=#2}{fill #1/.style={fill={#2}}},
  @/.list={
    -30=brown, 90=brown, 30=yellow, 150=yellow, -90=yellow,% for the triangles
    00=green, 01=red, 10=orange, 11=blue},%                  for the hexagons
  @/.style args={#1=#2}{
    polygon path #1/.style={polygon path={-30+#2*60}{a/sqrt 3}{3}}},
  @/.list={-30=0, 90=0, 30=1, 150=1, -90=1}]
\foreach[evaluate={\cols=int(isodd(\r)?7:6);}] \r in {1, ..., 4}
  \foreach[evaluate={\columnCheck=int(mod((\r-1)/2,2));}]\c in {1, ..., \cols}{
    \tikzset{shift={({2*a*(\c+iseven(\r)*.5)},2*a*.86602540378*\r)}}
    \draw[
      fill \ifodd\r\space1\else0\fi\ifodd\pgfinteval{\c+\columnCheck} 1\else0\fi,
      polygon path={0}{a}{6}];
    \unless\ifnum\c=7
      \foreach[expand list] \ang in {-30, 30%
        \ifnum\r<4 \ifnum\c=1 \ifodd\r , 90\fi\fi\fi
        \ifnum\c=1 \ifnum\r>1 \ifodd\r ,-90\else\ifnum\r=4 , 150\fi\fi\fi\fi
      } \draw[shift={(\ang:sqrt 3/1.5*a)}, fill \ang, polygon path \ang];
    \fi
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]